# Find the range of the given function

Tags: functions

> $$f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$$

Pretty straight forward question. I have a problem though in the final answer. I believe the answer should be R, as in all real numbers, since a square root can have both positive and negative values.

The answer is, however, $[0, \infty)$ which I feel is sorta correct, I but I need a proper explanation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what you wrote is only part of the definition of a function, what is the domain?

Comment: Generally, when dealing with reals, $\sqrt{x}$ means the non negative root of $x$. So, assuming that the domain of the above is $[2,\infty)$, the answer is the non negative reals.

Comment: @Riquelme ofc domain is $[2, \infty)$. It was really easy and that really wasn’t my question.

Comment: What @Riquelme probably meant was that your function makes sense on a bunch of domains. For instance, considering it as a function on $[2,3]$ would yield the image $[0,1]$ by the intermediate value theorem and monotonicity. You could even reasonably define it on $[0,1]$ and yield the image $i[0,1]$ as a function with complex values.

Comment: ***A*** square root can be positive or negative.  But ***THE*** square root is always non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short dictatorial answer:

$\sqrt {M} = x$ does *not* mean that $x^2 = M$.

$\sqrt {M} = x$ means that $x^2 = M$ ***AND*** that $x \ge 0$.

Slightly more friendly answer.

***A*** square root of $M$ is a number $x$ so that $x^2 = M$.  If $M > 0$ then $M$ has *two* square roots, a positive square root $x_1$ and a negative square root $x_2$.  The numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ are related in that $|x_1| = |x_2|$ and $x_2 = -x_1$.

We use the notation $\sqrt{M}$ to refer to the positive square root and therefore the negative square root would be the value $-\sqrt{M}$.

If $M = 0$, well there is only one possible $x$ so that $x^2 = 0$ and that is $x=0$.  As $0 = -0$ and $|0| = |-0| = 0$ we can consistantly defive $\sqrt{0} = 0 =-\sqrt{0}$.

And our *official* definition is $\sqrt{M}$ for an $M\ge 0$, means the non-negative square root of $M$, or in other words the number $x$ so that $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 = M$.

(Note: if $M < 0$ there there are no *real* square roots but there are two *complex* square roots, $x_1$ and $x_2$.  We still have the relationship $|x_1| = |x_2|$ and $x_2 = -x_1$ but we have neither of them are real and neither of them are positive and neither of them are negative.  I will not go into this here.)

Now often sometimes people will say "the square root of $49$ is $7$" when what they mean is "the *positive* square root of $49$ is $7$".  This is actually okay because it is understood *in context* that we are referring to the non-negative root.  But we must be careful in actually solving problems we recognize or presumptions.

If we ne to solve $x^2 + 4x = 21$ and we do

$x^2 + 4x + 4 = 25$

$(x+2)^2 = 25$ so

$\sqrt{(x+2)^2} = \sqrt 25$

We must be careful that we do not know for a fact that  $\sqrt{(x+2)^2} = x+2$.  Be definition, $\sqrt{(x+2)^2}$ means the *non-negative* value $w$ so that $w^2 = (x+2)^2$.  If $x+2$ is non-negative then $w$ *is* $x+2$ but if $x+2 < 0$ then $w=-(x+2)$.

It's easier, and our way of solving is to say

If $(x+2)^2 = 25$ then $x+2 =$ one or the other square roots of $25$.  Either $x+2 = \sqrt 25$, the positive one, or $x+2 = -\sqrt{25}$, the negative one.

Or in notation:

$x+2 = \pm \sqrt {25} = \pm 5$.

But I digress...

As a *function* $f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$ a function for each input of $x$ must have a single value output.  And it is the *non-negative* root.

So $\sqrt {x-2}\ge 0$.  And so the range must be a subset of $[0,\infty)$.

That is half the job.

The other half is to show that the range is *all* of $[0,\infty)$.   That is for any $y\in [0,\infty)$ there is one (or more) $x$ so that $f(x) = y$.

And we can show that.  If $f(x) = y\ge 0$ then $\sqrt{x-2} = y$ so $x-2 =(\sqrt{x-2})^2=y^2$ or $x = y^2 + 2 $ .  As $x = y^2 + 2$ is always an acceptable real value, then for every $y\in [0,\infty)$ we have $y$ is in the range of $f$ and the range of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$.

!!!!!HOWEVER!!!!!!!

we have completely overlooked what the *DOMAIN* of $f$ is!  And that is an *essential* part of the definition of any functio; much more important than that range.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that we are considering $f$ as a function, so its values must be uniquely defined! In other words, $f(6)=2$, not $-2$.

Unless specified otherwise, we consider square roots to take only positive values. It'd be a different story if you were trying to solve an equation like $x^2=9$ and needed to take square roots in an intermediate steps. You should write then $x= \pm \sqrt{9}$ rather than $x=\sqrt{9}$ when referring to both solutions simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\sqrt{}$ means "the *nonnegative* square root of." If we allow it to mean "square root of," then it would not define a function in the classical sense. That is, it would not be single-valued. Hence, they restricted the range to the nonnegative axis.

Answer (score -1):

Domain of f(X) is $2\le X < \infty$

f(X) is continuous over the interval $2\le X < \infty$

So you can plug 2 in f(X)

f(X)=0

So range of f(X) is $0 \le f(X) < \infty$

Comment: ...where you've used a bunch of things, like $f$ being increasing, continuous and tending to $\infty$. Also $\infty$ definitely isn't in the range.